# Continuity of a functional whose kernel is weakly closed

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $f$ be a linear functional on $X$ such that kernel of $f$ is **weakly** closed. Can we say that $f$ is a member of $X^*$, the continuous dual of $X$.

We know that given any $f\in X^*$, $\ker f=f^{-1}\{0\}$, which is weakly closed. The question here asks about the converse.

I am a beginner in functional analysis and a detail answer will be of very much help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kernel of $f$ is a convex set. A convex set is weakly closed iff it is closed in the norm. [See Theorem 3.12 in Rudin's FA]. Hence, the kernel of $f$ is closed in the norm topology and this is equivalent to continuity of $f$.

Comment: Thankyou! @Kaviramamurthy for your answer. I have a query in this context. Suppose that $H$ is a hyperplane in $X$ which is closed with respect to the weak topology in $X$. Since $H$ is of codimension $1$, we can find a linear functional containing $H$ in its kernel. The argument you posed above ensures that $f$ is norm continuous. does this work? or I am missing something! Thankyou again for your kind reply.

Comment: It is correct.  You are not missing anythng. @srm99